# .NET Regex question

Tags: .net, regex

Can someone explain why the "1" was included in the first regex group instead of the 2nd?

```
Match match = Regex.Match("q10", @"(\w+)(\d+)");
//Ugh, Regex group indicies are 1-based not 0-based.
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); //Expected "q" got "q1"
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value); //Expected "10" got "0"
```

Comment: BTW, they're not really 1-based. Group 0 should contain the entire match.

Comment: @Justin yeah, I know but it's not really a one of the groups, it's the match itself, so it doesn't really feel like it should be part of the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` matches alpha**numeric** characters (and underscores).

You want `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should've RTFM.  For some reason I though it was just alpha, and it my brain told me that "w" stood for "word"

Comment: It actually does stand for word.

Comment: numbers aren't words my my book! *facepalm* Oh well, now I know.  Until I forget again :p

Answer (score 2):

The regex is matching greedily, so `(\w+)` covers as much as it can before `(\d+)`. Since `1` is a word character, it's captured in the first group by `\w`.

You can capture the way you want by using this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("q10", @"([a-z]+)(\d+)");
```

Comment: The problem was me misremembering what \w was, but +1 since it could be helpful to others.